# How to reflect Generic Type Parameters in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, parameters

Consider the following generic classes

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

List<T>

CustomHashMap<K, V>
```

Is it possible to reflect back the names given to the generic type parameters?

For Example

```
"TKey", "TValue"

"T"

"K", "V"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<string> GetGenericArgumentNames(Type type)
    {
        if (!type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        {
            type = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        }

        foreach (var typeArg in type.GetGenericArguments())
        {
            yield return typeArg.Name;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // For a raw type
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", GetGenericArgumentNames(typeof(Foo<>))));
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", GetGenericArgumentNames(typeof(Foo<Quux>))));
    }

}

class Foo<TBar> {}

class Quux {}
```

Comment: Vote++; // Works like a charm! :-)

Comment: @activwerx Changed the code to give a nice utility function that will work on generic type definitions and instantiations.